# NServiceBus initialization failing in MVC when I pass some types to scan

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nservicebus, nservicebus3

In my bootstrapper I start by doing this:

```
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();

        InitializeNServiceBus(container);

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        ...
    }
```

And the content of InitializeNServiceBus is like this:

```
    private static void InitializeNServiceBus(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var typesToScan = new [] {
            typeof (RequestPasswordResetCommand),
            typeof (CreateAccountCommand)
        };

        Configure.With(typesToScan)
            .DefineEndpointName("somequeueonmysystem")
            .UnityBuilder(container)
            .XmlSerializer()
            //.MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
            .DisableRavenInstall()
            .DisableSecondLevelRetries() //we need timeout manager for this
            .DisableTimeoutManager() //we need raven db or similar for this //.RunTimeoutManager()
            .MsmqTransport()
                .IsTransactional(false)
                .PurgeOnStartup(false)
            .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
                .IsTransactional(true)
            .UnicastBus()
                .ImpersonateSender(false)
            .SendOnly();
            //.CreateBus()
            //    .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install()); 
    }
```

However when I open my MVC application I get:

**Static property requires null instance, non-static property requires non-null instance.
Parameter name: expression**

The source of the error is indicated here:

```
Line 82: 
Line 83:             Configure.With(typesToScan)
Line 84:                 .DefineEndpointName("InCityS.Events.UI.Nuvonet")
Line 85:                 .UnityBuilder(container)
```

The stacktrace:

```
[ArgumentException: Static property requires null instance, non-static property requires non-null instance.
Parameter name: expression]
   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(Expression expression, PropertyInfo property) +4114402
   NServiceBus.Utils.Reflection.DelegateFactory.Create(PropertyInfo property) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\utils\NServiceBus.Utils.Reflection\DelegateFactory.cs:91
   NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.XmlMessageSerializer.InitType(Type t) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\impl\Serializers\NServiceBus.Serializers.XML\XmlMessageSerializer.cs:133
   NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.XmlMessageSerializer.InitType(Type t) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\impl\Serializers\NServiceBus.Serializers.XML\XmlMessageSerializer.cs:138
   NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.XmlMessageSerializer.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 types) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\impl\Serializers\NServiceBus.Serializers.XML\XmlMessageSerializer.cs:948
   NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.Config.MessageTypesInitializer.Run() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\impl\Serializers\NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.Config\MessageTypesInitializer.cs:20
   NServiceBus.Configure.<Initialize>b__d(IWantToRunWhenConfigurationIsComplete o) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\config\NServiceBus.Config\Configure.cs:305
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action) +10722241
   NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\config\NServiceBus.Config\Configure.cs:304
   NServiceBus.Configure.SendOnly() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\config\NServiceBus.Config\Configure.cs:364
   InCityS.UI.Open.Bootstrapper.InitializeNServiceBus(IUnityContainer container) in d:\Data_nobackup\Projects\InCityS\trunk\UI\InCityS.UI.Open\Bootstrapper.cs:83
   InCityS.UI.Open.Bootstrapper.Initialise() in d:\Data_nobackup\Projects\InCityS\trunk\UI\InCityS.UI.Open\Bootstrapper.cs:53
   InCityS.UI.Open.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in d:\Data_nobackup\Projects\InCityS\trunk\UI\InCityS.UI.Open\Global.asax.cs:79

[HttpException (0x80004005): Static property requires null instance, non-static property requires non-null instance.
Parameter name: expression]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9859725
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Static property requires null instance, non-static property requires non-null instance.
Parameter name: expression]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873912
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

When I changes typesToScan to

```
var typesToScan = new Type[]{};
```

the application works again, but of course once I try to put something on the Bus it fails saying it doesn't know the type through the Scanned Types.

Anyone knows where to look or has experience with this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem detected.
One of the messages I added through the types to scan had a property which was op type 'CultureInfo' which doesn't play well with the serialization.

```
namespace InCityS.BL.Account.Messages
{
    public class CreateAccountCommand : ICommand
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }
    }
}
```

was replaced by:

```
namespace InCityS.BL.Account.Messages
{
    public class CreateAccountCommand : ICommand
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Culture { get; set; }
    }
 }
```